# Updating VS TFS 2010 file that is NOT in a project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In our source control, we have a dependencies folder. It is not part of any project, but shared by a few. I have to update a couple files in there, but not sure how to go about updating these files and adding check-in notes.

How can I do this? Thanks.

EDIT: I should mention. These are DLLs, so it's not like I can edit them directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Team Explorer
2. Open the Team Project
3. Double-click the "Source Control" node

This will display the Source Control Explorer, which will let you check out and check back in.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually check out the files, then edit them in your favorite editor, and manually check them back in.

Comment: In the case of binaries (assemblies), your edit will obviously be copying the newer version over the existing one.